# Factory service and injection .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I have service factory in .NET Core 3.1. Each service implements `IService` and each service has arguments in the constructor, (there is no parameterless ctors)

What is the best way to inject service factory?

--Update with current solution--

```cs
public interface IServiceFactory 
{
   IService Create(string serviceType);
}


public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory 
{
 public IService[] services;

 public ServiceFactory(IService[] services)
 {
   this.services = services;
 }

  public IService Create(string serviceType)
  {
    return services.First(s => s.ServiceName == serviceType);
  }
}

public interface IService
{
    string ServiceName { get; }
    bool Send();
}

public class ServiceA : IService
{
    private ISrv1 srv1:
    private ISrv2 srv2;

    public ServiceA(ISrv1 srv1, ISrv2 srv2)
    {
        this.srv1 = srv1;
        this.srv2 = srv2;
    }

    public ServiceName => return "serviceA";

    public bool Send()
    {
    var data = srv1.GetData();
    var msg = new MessageData 
     {
      Id = data.Id,
      Email = data.MailAddress
    };
  
   return srv2.Send(msg);
  }
}

//not full class just the idea for sending message when getting message data from 
//different services
public class ServiceB : IService
{

    public ServiceB()
    {
    }

    public ServiceName => return "serviceB";

    public bool Send() => false;
}
```

How the factory should create the correct service with all dependencies?
And how to register correctly the services and the factory in configue services?

For now the solution is

```
services.AddTransient<IServiceFactory>(c =>
  new ServiceFactory(new INotificationService[]
  {
     new ServiceA(c.GetService<ISrv1>(),c.GetService<ISrv2>()),
     new ServiceB();
  }));
```

Comment: Why d you need one? .NET Core's DI will create an instance of any registered type. If you want to perform a specialized actin you can register a factory faction to create the instance. If you use eg `services.AddTransient<ServiceA>(); services.AddTransient<IService1,Service1>(); services.AddTransient<IService2,Service2>();` you'll be able to ask for a `ServiceA` and the DI container will create the necessary `Service1` and `Service2` instnances

Comment: How is your factory expected to distinct between the services? Does `IServiceFactory` have a `IService Create(string name)` method?

Comment: Can you update your question to include actual names of interfaces and classes in your application? When it comes to questions about DI, the correct answer typically highly depends on the context.

Comment: A updated my question. The idea is to get the correct service in runtime by service type. I wonder what is the best way to inject service factory in .net core. 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

As a solution I used IServiceProvider in the FactoryService for getting the correct service by the givven type in runtime.
I registered the services as following

```
services.AddScoped<IServiceFactory, ServiceFactory>();
        services.AddScoped<ServiceA>()
            .AddScoped<IService, ServiceA>(c => c.GetService<ServiceA>());
        services.AddScoped<ServiceB>()
            .AddScoped<IService, ServiceB>(c => c.GetService<ServiceB>());
```